# Creating an object inside an object through parameters - Java

Tags: java, class, object, oop

So I have three classes which have to integrate with each other. They keep data about a continent, a country in the continent and a mountain peak in the country.

Everything is ok, but I just can't figure out how I'm supposed to enter an object into the parameters of another object.

Example:

```
public Country(String name, Peak newPeak) {
    this.name = name;
    peaks.add(new Peak(name, height));
}
```

main method:

```
public class Main {

    Continent Europe = new Continent();

    Country Germany = new Country("Germany", new Peak("The Alps", 3456);
    Europe.addCountry(Germany);

}
```

My main should look like this.

Comment: If you pass a Peak instance use it directly, just do `peaks.add(newPeak)`

Comment: how about the parameters of newPeak

Comment: In the main code, how do you call all that ? How do you choose Country name ?

Comment: Using the "new" keyword, eg. continent Asia = new continent(new Country(...), new Peak(...));

Comment: but I also have an addCountry method which has Country and Peak as parameters

Comment: That doesn't explain me where that code runs. Where does come from the country name ? Can you [edit] your post to show the code where `continent Asia = new continent(new Country(...), new Peak(...));` is ?

Comment: Where is `peaks` defined?

Comment: in my Country class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating the instance of the Country-object you either enter an already created  Peak:

```
Peak p = new Peak(peakName, height);

Country c = new Country(countryName, p);
```

or you call the constructor of Peak instead of the Peak-object:

```
Country c = new Country(countryName, new Peak(peakName, height));
```

One more thing: be careful with the naming of your variables. In your example the peak and the country would have the same names.

Comment: Yeah I think I'll do that, I tried to create everything just in the Continent constructor which didn't work. Thanks everyone!